# Selenium WebDriver sendkeys type incorrect value to input field if value that typing contains forward slash (/)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

Selenium WebDriver sendkeys method sometimes type incorrect value to text area of input field, if value that typing contains forward slash (/) character.
For examlple

element located in:

```
<input id="dp1416998181403" class="single-value hasDatepicker" type="text" maxlength="10" value="12/31/2010" style="width: 67px;">
```

code

```
String a = "12/31/2014"
driver.findElement(By.id("dp1416998181403")).sendKeys(a);
```

in some case actual value that typed is equals: 31/2014 instead of 12/31/2014
or 2014 instead of 12/31/2014
This problem isn't reproduce always
I noticed, in some case, Selenium type first 3 character (12/), then delete them and type rest of character (31/2014)

Has anybody have the same problem?
I found a problem with typing a /, but problem was that / changing to 7 when typing

Comment: You probably have some kind of datrepicker and that's what causing it not selenium. Try to send it as date time instead of string

Comment: selenium take only String as an argument in sendkeys method

Comment: I know it does. I was telling you to convert datetime to string afterwards and see [this](http://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html) if your site has date picker

Comment: in that example that you wrote, usual String use to type, only difference is that there no / in String. When I delete / from my string = selenium just type value without /

Answer (score 0):

@user3293822 :

Not Really But can you try to add explicit wait before you send keys , Here is an example of what you can do..I am sure you will not find any data loss during execution.

```
String a = "12/31/2014";
WebDriverWait  Test_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Test_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("dp1416998181403"))).sendKeys(a);
```

Try the above and let me know what happens

Comment: to find an element i have already used Wait. Such as WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));. elementToBeClickable i dont use becouse some times test can failed with ElementNotClickableException. I am shure that element is present and that selenium have find element

Comment: What i believe here in the situation where data is getting skipped by the script.. Here some thing we have to look at is the speed of the script at which it is getting executed. Lets try implementing two things..First one i,ll Suggest more. i.e putting Thread.sleep(); before we send keys or second  try selenium. Set Speed.

Comment: selenium.SetSpeed deleted from WebDriver that i used. Selenium Server contain setSpeed only. I put Thread.sleep(250) between clear and sendKeys methos

Comment: I think it is really problem with execution speed, When i debug test - everything work correctly. But i can't set speed of execution selenium sendKeys method